# How to identify cross-site requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, setcookie

I am having issues in reading cookies sent/set by the server in the response headers (Set-Cookie)

I wanted to understand if the below 2 scenarios constitute a cross-site

1. UI is running on http://localhost:3000 and server which sets the cookie is on say other local host http://172.10.25.63:8089
2. UI is running on http://myui.app.dev.something.myhost.net and server which sets the cookie is on say other host http://myservice.app.dev.something.myhost.net

Do the below 2 scenarios have a cross-site request ?

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of Ajax, those are all cross-origin requests (which needs the `useCredentials` flag on the client and permission from CORS including a preflight on the server).

For the purposes of Cookies being available on both URLs, for case (1) they are different and for case (2) since they share a common set of domains (`app.dev.somethings.myhost.net`) they can share cookies if the `domain` parameter is set correctly in the `Set-Cookie` response header.

Comment: Yes right...For (2) , everything is same except http://{THIS_CHANGES}.app.dev.something.myhost.net

Comment: But when you say, domain parameter is set correctly in the Set-Cookie response header, is that to be done explicitly on the server-side ?

Comment: Yes (unless the cookie was created with client-side JS in the first place).

Comment: Just a couple of follow up questions before we close-
1. Can Set-Cookie be set in the response headers of a GET request ?
2. Since it is a GET request I am making, I am not setting withCredentials. But I want to read the cookie on UI set via server in the response headers via Set-Cookie

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) If you want a GET request with credentials then you need to set `withCredentials` on the GET request!

Comment: Thanks..and what about the Domain attribute considering UI is at http://myui.app.dev.something.myhost.net and is making request to server at http://myservice.app.dev.something.myhost.net ?

Comment: It's only relevant if the request that set it and the request that needs to send it are going to different subdomains.

Comment: Ok..I just tried setting withCredentials  to true and I get the following error....
response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check The value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response must not be wildcard *

Comment: Yes, you do need to configure CORS more tightly to deal with credentials.

Comment: I did not entirely get that...You mean setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to something else ?

Comment: Yes, you have to explicitly state the origin instead of using the wildcard.

Comment: In my case, would the Origin have to be set to the string http ://myui.app.dev.something.myhost.net

Comment: Yes, that looks right

Comment: Also since you mentioned mine is not a cross-site setup, I assume the SameSite should not matter either ways i.e. whether it is set to None or left as default 
Would that be correct ?

Comment: Also not sure if withCredentialsis needed...Since just to clarify again, for this initial GET request, I am expecting the cookie in the response...so this is not the request where cookie is sent to the server, but instead I am expecting it to read in the response of this GET request